# PHP PDO sqlsrv for SQL Server not entering READ UNCOMMITTED

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv

Using PHP and PDO we connect to a Microsoft SQL server. Some of our connections we want to run as READ UNCOMMITTED.

I do most of my dev work on a Mac and test/deploy on a Windows box. I found that using dblib(FreeTDS) on Mac or Linux entering READ UNCOMMITTED works as expected, yet on Windows using sqlsrv (the official MS driver) it does not.

Here is a simple script I wrote to test it.

```
$pdo = new PDO ("sqlsrv:server=$hostname;database=$dbname",$username,$pw);


$stmtIsolationLevel = $pdo->prepare(
"SELECT CASE transaction_isolation_level 
WHEN 1 THEN 'ReadUncommitted' 
WHEN 2 THEN 'ReadCommitted' 
END AS TRANSACTION_ISOLATION_LEVEL 
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions 
where session_id = @@SPID"
);

$stmtSetUncommitted = $pdo->prepare("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED");

//output transaction level
$stmtIsolationLevel->execute();
$results = $stmtIsolationLevel->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $results[0]['TRANSACTION_ISOLATION_LEVEL'] . "\n";

//set to READ UNCOMMITTED"
$stmtSetUncommitted->execute();
$results = $stmtSetUncommitted->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//output transaction level
$stmtIsolationLevel->execute();
$results = $stmtIsolationLevel->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $results[0]['TRANSACTION_ISOLATION_LEVEL'] . "\n";
```

On Mac or Linux this outputs:
ReadCommitted
ReadUncommitted

On Windows:
ReadCommitted
ReadCommitted

Notes:
The connection string is different, on a mac it would be "dblib:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname"

I tried including the set transaction statement in the same statement where I test what it's set to and I get the same result.

I have also tried setting READ UNCOMMITTED at connection time using the constant flag for PDO::SQLSRV but that throws an odd exception.

```
$pdo = new PDO ("sqlsrv:server=$hostname;database=$dbname",$username,$pw,[PDO::SQLSRV_TXN_READ_UNCOMMITTED]);
```

This results in a PDOException: "The auto-commit mode cannot be changed for this driver"

Comment: What version of MS SQL do you use? And what is driver version? And PHP version? To retrive a value of auto-commit attribute for your connection try: `echo $pdo->getAttribute(constant("PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT"));`

Comment: Interesting question. I played with your code and the only way, when it worked as you want, was calling `$pdo->exec("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED");` instead of prepared statement. `$pdo->query()` also didn't work. You can also change isolation level when you create PDO instance. This path is described in doc.

Comment: That works, skipping prepared does it. Strange. I did try setting it at creation as you can see in my edit from a couple of days ago, that causes an exception.

Comment: Yep I know. You call PDO constructor in bad way. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018320/pdoexception-the-auto-commit-mode-cannot-be-changed-for-this-driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018320/pdoexception-the-auto-commit-mode-cannot-be-changed-for-this-driver).

Answer (score 0):

You must set this way:

```
$isolationLevel = PDO::SQLSRV_TXN_READ_UNCOMMITTED; 

$pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$hostname;database=$dbname; TransactionIsolation=".$isolationLevel, $username,$pw);
```