# PDOException: "The auto-commit mode cannot be changed for this driver"

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm trying to get PDO connecting to an SQL server to enter READ UNCOMMITTED, according to various sources (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296183(v=sql.105).aspx) this is how you do it.

```
$pdo = new PDO ("sqlsrv:server=$hostname;database=$dbname",$username,$pw,[PDO::SQLSRV_TXN_READ_UNCOMMITTED]);
```

This results in a PDOException: "The auto-commit mode cannot be changed for this driver"

Answer (score 2):

When you're using PDO, you have to use this form:

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=".$hostname. 
               ";Database=".$database. 
               ";TransactionIsolation=".PDO::SQLSRV_TXN_READ_UNCOMMITTED, 
                $username, $pw);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628167.aspx